# How to split with multiple bracket

Tags: python

So I want to do something like this
"(1.0)" which returns ["1","0"]
similarly "((1.0).1)" which returns ["(1.0)", "1")

How do i do this python? Thanks for the help

so basically I want to break the string "(1.0)" into a list [1,0] where the dot is the separator.

some examples

((1.0).(2.0)) -> [(1.0), (2.0)]

(((1.0).(2.0)).1) -> [((1.0).(2.0)), 1]

I hope this is more clear.

Comment: Is not clear (at least to me) what exactly are you trying to do. Can you expand?

Comment: I am guessing at your meaning somewhat: You have a sequence of digits, dots, left parentheses, and right parentheses, in a string.  You want to, first, remove the outermost pair of parentheses, and second, split the remaining string into a sequence of strings at dots *that are not enclosed in parentheses*.  You have not said what should happen if parentheses are not properly nested, or if there is no outermost pair of parentheses.  How much of that is correct?  Please clarify the unspecified cases.

Comment: the outermost parentheses will always be there and they will always be properly nested.

Comment: Your examples seem a bit vague...is everything a string?  Are your example results supposed to be valid Python types?  `[(1.0), (2.0)]` is, but is equivalent to `[1.0, 2.0]`, but then `[((1.0).(2.0)), 1]` is illegal as you're trying to access the `2.0` attribute of `1.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my version:

```
def countPar(s):
    s=s[1:-1]
    openPar=0
    for (i,c) in enumerate(s):
        if c=="(":
            openPar+=1
        elif c==")":
            openPar-=1
        if openPar==0:
            break
    return [s[0:i+1],s[i+2:]]
```

Comment: Why are you discarding the second item of the tuple from `enumerate`? It would have saved you two `s[i]`s.

Comment: Yep, didn't see that. In fact, I was using range(len(s)), but I try to use enumerate more. And I failed… I'm editing right now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to build a little parser. Iterate through the characters of the string, keeping track of the current nesting level of parentheses. Then you can detect the `.` you care about by checking that first, the character is a `.`, and second, there's only one level of parentheses open at that point. Then just place the characters in one buffer or another depending on whether you've reached that `.` or not.